# fabricjs sendBackwards and sendToBack functions are not working properly

Tags: fabricjs

Please try to select one of the text elements here http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink and click on the send backward button. Nothing changes. If you deselect the element by clicking on an empty space on the canvas, it works again. And if after that you reselect the element, it goes wrong again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fabricjs 1.6.3: why active object is always shown on top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247337/fabricjs-1-6-3-why-active-object-is-always-shown-on-top)

Comment: No it's not. They have a hovering problem, mine is about the send to back and bring to front buttons.

Comment: Check the option for `preserveObjectStacking` in the demo and then try moving things forward and back.